# Difference between refunding and cancelling an In-App Billing order

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play-services

Based on the Trivial Drive sample, I was wondering what the difference was between refunding and cancelling an order for a managed, non-consumable product, the Premium car. Because, it's been about a week now since I've **refunded** the order to my test account via Google's Merchant Center, and yet the Premium order is still recognized as purchased (state 0 after using premiumPurchase.getPurchaseState()) and owned in the inventory after querying it...

Could it be perhaps because I didn't **cancel** the order via the Merchant Center as follows (depicted in the red circle):

[image]

... If I have to cancel it, is the SO answer ([In-App Billing v3 - Don't detect refund](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13861625/in-app-billing-v3-dont-detect-refund)) still valid in terms of how **long** it'll take to process? Because, I found out that other SO answers suggest that I have to handle the refund process myself like the previous In-App Billing version, v2.

Comment: Did you find your answer?