# Unexpected return by getPurchaseState() return one while purchaseState is returning zero in Google play billing library for the same purchase record

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I had a refunded non-consumable acknowledged purchase, using Google play billing 2.1.0

`Purchase.PurchasesResult purchasesResult = billingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP);`

`for(purchase in purchasesResult)`

`purchase.getPurchaseState()` return 1

but `purchase.toString()` `purchaseState` return 0

I use `Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED` to check for state but it return 1

Don't know what is the number for the real PURCHASED state or the refunded state

Comment: Maybe it will help you. See this link: [Detect refunded managed in-app purchase android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57802500/detect-refunded-managed-in-app-purchase-android-iap-2-0-3/62733257#62733257)

Comment: Ha, I'm literally running into that right now. If you look at the code it seems extremely broken...not sure how on earth this is supposed to qualify for spec. "case 4:
            return 2;
        default:
            return 1;
        }"
My case is a simple account hold scenario: purchase is still returned, but getPurchaseState() is returning 1 which is OK, even though I would expect 0 (unknown) or 2 (pending) when there is an issue with payment.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue

What worked for me? or a work around can be. handling the JSON response manually-

```
Purchase purchase = purchases.get(0);   //"purchases" is the list of purchases returned

boolean isPurchased = false;
try {
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(purchase.getOriginalJson());
int purchaseState = (int) jsonObject.get("purchaseState");
                            
isPurchased = purchaseState == Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED;
                                        
log.d(TAG, "DEBUGLOGS isExistingSubscriber() jsonObject.get(purchseState)- " + jsonObject.get("purchaseState"));
} catch (JSONException e) {
   throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Hope it helps!